# How to get rid of the table of contents sidebar in LaTeX Beamer ?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm making a presentation with Beamer and I'm using the Hannover theme with the table of contents sidebar which is on each slide. I'd like not to show it on the first slide where is the title, the authors,... How can I do that ?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}


\title[]{Projet Q2: Mag-Id-Tag !}
\subtitle{\color{black}{Groupe 11.65}}
\author[]{Adrien Farinelle \and Emile Fourneau \and Antoine Gauthier \and Thibault Hellings \and Vincent Nadrin \and Charles Snyers}
\date{23 juin 2011}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Table des matières}
\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{Introduction}

\section{Sous-blocs du système}

\section{Validation du système}

\section{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `plain` frame style:

```
\frame[plain]{\titlepage}
```

Comment: Thanks but even if there is no sidebar the title isn't centred, how can I fix that ?

Comment: @snickers Here's a way: [How to center the titleframe in Hannover theme (beamer)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24402/how-to-center-the-titleframe-in-hannover-theme-beamer)

Comment: Any idea how this `\frame[plain]{\titlepage}` could work inside LyX?