# How to center the titleframe in Hannover theme (beamer)?

Tags: macros, beamer, titles

I am using the Hannover theme in beamer and I am using the title frame as plain

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Hannover}%{CambridgeUS}%
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\title[Title]{Centering Title frame}
\author[Gopi]{Gopi}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{logo}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: picture of frame title not centered]
[image: picture of frame title without "plain" not centered]

Because it was not obvious on the first picture (white on white, I have added the same picture without the option "plain" on the frame). My point is that I would like that with the option plain the frame forget about the hannover theme and centers the whole frame.

I tried to put a \hspace{-xpt} before the frame but it did not seem to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could `\hoffset` to move the content of the frame to the left, by the half amount of the sidebar width:

```
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\setlength{\hoffset}{-.5\beamer@sidebarwidth}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
    ...
\end{frame}
\endgroup
```

I used `\begingroup`and `\endgroup` to limit the effect of the change to `\hoffset` to just this frame. `\makeatletter` and `\makeatletter` are necessary for accessing the internal macro `\beamer@sidebarwidth`.

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore. Any idea what might work now?

Comment: @luchonacho Perhaps tell us what "doesn't work" means in your case. And you may post a new question if you like.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I am trying to center the title for another beamer template, and it doesn't work. Is your solution unique to the Hannover theme? I get ``Undefined control sequence. \setlength{\hoffset}{-.5\beamer@sidebarwidth}``

Comment: @luchonacho Possibly! For example, a beamer theme without a sidebar doesn't need a `\beamer@sidebarwidth` length. Your case may be different, so it would be a good idea to post a new question with all template information.

Comment: Wow this is clever! :) Thank you, exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If the background of the title page isn't white -- for instance, if filled with the `\fill` from tikz, --  then the Stefan's solution won't work as intended: the filled area will be shifted to the left exposing the white background.  My solution is to put the title page into a `minibox` and then shift it by half of the sidebar width:

```
\renewcommand\makebeamertitle{
  {
    \begin{frame}[plain]
      \makeatletter
      \hspace*{-0.5\beamer@sidebarwidth}
      \begin{minipage}[c][\textheight]{\textwidth}
        \maketitle
      \end{minipage}
      \makeatother
    \end{frame}
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to give this as a minimal working example? I'm having this problem, but can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to simply define a custom title page:

In the preamble:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]
{
  \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
  \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par
  \bigskip
  \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par
  \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par
  \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic
}
```

Comment: But this won't remove the additional margin from the sidebar. Try this with a longer title and you will see that the left margin is still much bigger than the right one.