# Hide navigation information in sidebar on title page and TOC page (beamer)

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, titles

Edited for clarity: 
I am trying to remove the navigation information in the sidebar that lists a TOC on the title page and the TOC page in a beamer presentation.  I still want the sidebar to appear for presentation background consistency, but I want it to be blank.  I'm using the PaloAlto theme.

I have found a work around for the title page by setting the background of the title page as a rectangle the size and colour of the sidebar on top of the sidebar by using \addtobeamertemplate{title page}, but this approach doesn't work for the TOC page as I can't find a way to link to that page specifically through the template definition.

Is there an easier way to hide the sidebar on only the title page and TOC page?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, from a comment, the idea is to remove only the information contained in the sidebar and not the sidebar itself; if this is so, then you can simply set the `sidebar left` template to be empty for those frames and then restore its original meaning with the `sidebar theme` option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}[sidebar theme]
\section{Test Section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sam you're welcome! May I suggest you to edit the title of the question to make it clear that you only want to hide the information on the sidebar? As it is now, the tile suggests that the intent is to hide the sidebar altogether.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina And how do we suppress the sidebar altogether, just in the very first frame (titlepage)?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Seems to be answered at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21103/8272. However, I can't make it work inside LyX.

Answer (score 8):

you can add the `plain` option to the frame.

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \frametitle{}  % recover the header
    a frame without sidebar
\end{frame}
```

Comment: This removes any background format I have for the page, including the header and footer.  Is there a way to preserve the background, and if possible a sidebar colour block, just without the TOC content for specific slides?  I'm trying to keep the slide design consistent but without the TOC content on certain slides.

Comment: If you add `\frametitle{}` you will probably recover the header. Maybe it is a way to create a new page style take a look at the manual, I do not know.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: correct, I only want to remove the navigation info from the sidebar for the title page frame and the TOC page frame