# span of sidebar in beamerposter, with title in the header

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I am making a poster using beamerposter and trying to create my own theme. But I'm having trouble with the sidebar. I want the sidebar to be on the left hand side along the entire height of the poster. However, when I put the title in the header, the sidebar disappears from the header. It looks like this:

[image]

example code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[orientation=landscape,width=46in, height=42in,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\definecolor{Light}{gray}{.80}
\definecolor{dgreen}{rgb}{0.,0.6,0.}


\makeatletter

% sidebar
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=0.075\paperwidth}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}[vertical shading][top=green!23!blue!49, bottom=green!15!blue!42]

% headline
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.075\paperwidth,ht=0ex,dp=0ex,center]{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.92\paperwidth,ht=4ex,dp=0ex,center]{}

    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }

\hbox{
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.08\paperwidth,ht=0ex,dp=1ex,center]{}

  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.92\paperwidth]{headline}
                \centering
        \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg}\textbf{\veryHuge{\inserttitle}}\\[1ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
}

\def\beamer@andinst{\\[0.15em]}


\makeatother



\title{Title of the poster}
\author{\textcolor{dgreen}{author 1}\inst{1} \and author 2\inst{1} \and author 3\inst{2} }
\institute{\inst{1} Institution 1  \and %
            \inst{2} Institution 2 }
\date{}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{} 

contents

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I also tried putting everything in a separate .sty file. When I did that for some reason the sidebar only spanned part of the poster. But when I define the sidebar inside the main .tex file, it does span the entire height of the page before I put the title in the header. When I put the title/author in the header the outcome looks like the image above. But I would like the sidebar to span the whole page. I would appreciate help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67200

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, I did try the method in the other post. For some reason it doesn't work in my case. I get an error with `\ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt ... \fi`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\raisebox` to move the bar upwards:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[orientation=landscape,width=46in, height=42in,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}

\definecolor{Light}{gray}{.80}
\definecolor{dgreen}{rgb}{0.,0.6,0.}

% sidebar
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=0.075\paperwidth}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}[vertical shading][top=green!23!blue!49, bottom=green!15!blue!42]

% headline
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\headheight\relax}{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.92\paperwidth]{headline}
              \vskip2cm
        \centering
        \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg}\textbf{\veryHuge{\inserttitle}}\\[1ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
      \end{beamercolorbox}
    }
}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@andinst{\\[0.15em]}
\makeatother

\title{Title of the poster}
\author{\textcolor{dgreen}{author 1}\inst{1} \and author 2\inst{1} \and author 3\inst{2} }
\institute{\inst{1} Institution 1  \and %
            \inst{2} Institution 2 }
\date{}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

contents

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]