# How to customize selected slides in latex?

Tags: beamer

I'm new at using `beamer`, and I would really appreciate your help. Preparing a presentation I've chosen the `Goettingen` theme, which places a sidebar showing the contents for each of the slides. I would like to remove it from the title page and the table of contents, so frames 1 and 2 would

1. show a different them with the same colourtheme, or
2. find a command to remove the sidebar from the selected frames.

This is mi minimal example,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Goettingen}     
  \usecolortheme{beaver} 
  \usefonttheme{default}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\title[ShortTitle]{Fulltitle}
\author{GV, R}
\institute{University}
\date{16 de Junio, 2014}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame} 
  \frametitle{Contents}
  \framesubtitle{}
  \tableofcontents
 \end{frame}

....

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe the following question/answer can help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59631/hide-navigation-information-in-sidebar-on-title-page-and-toc-page-beamer